# How do I create a React and ASP.net Core (typescript) project in Visual Studio Code? .net 8

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm able to create a project from template named, "React and ASP.net Core (typescript)" in Visual Studio Community - targeting .net 8 - on a windows machine. However, when I try to do the same with Visual Studio Code on a mac I am unable to find a template that targets the latest .net framework.

As a workaround I tried pulling the VS Community created project into VS Code. I get an error **"Only one compilation unit can have top-level statements."**

I also tried changing the target of a template created in VSCode but was unsuccessful as I couldn't find all the references and kept getting errors about the target .net version.